# Translating Swift enums with associated values to C++

Tags: c++, std-variant

In Swift you can have an enum type with [associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html).

```swift
enum Thing {
   case num(Int)
   case two(String, Double)
   case other
}
var t: Thing = .num(123)
t = .two("a", 6.022)
t = .other
```

From what I'm reading, you can can do a similar thing in C++ by using  [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). It has less syntactic sugar.

But the compiler complains if you give `void` to `std::variant`, so how would you represent the `other` case above? Maybe an ignored integer? Or is there better way to translate something like that enum type to C++?

```cpp
std::variant<int, pair<string, double>, void>  // error
std::variant<int, pair<string, double>, int>   // okay
```

Compiler error from Clang:

> ... "variant can not have a void type as an alternative."

(If I wanted to refer to that variant as `Thing` I could use a typedef or wrap it in a `struct`.)

Comment: Use [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) as your `void` stand-in for `std::variant`.

Comment: `void` is not a type that you can have objects of.

Comment: @Eljay Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `void` cannot be instantiated, you'll need some stand-in type to represent `void`.

You could make your own, `struct void_t{};`, or you could use the [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) which is provided in C++17 and later.